# Add controller in visual studio 2019 gives error. The value -1 out of range

Tags: visual-studio, controller, visual-studio-2019

Add controller in visual studio 2019 gives error.

```
Error running the selected code generator :" value -1 is outside 
the acceptable [0,2147483647] range. Parameter name :value"
```

Comment: [seems like a bug in VS 2019 fixed in 16.2.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.2.4)

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config file might be open in editor.
 Please close the web.config file & try again